# Display blob as doc file React

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for a solution to display doc file in React app. I am using react-docx library to create a file I need and the documentation says we can do whatever we want with the binary file created. Anyway it shows only examples to save it on computer. What I wanna do is to make this blob tyle file display in a browser as doc. I wanted to use preview-docx library for that but it has very poor documentation and I am not sure if that would be a solution. Anyway there is another library like react-doc-viewer but it accepts only strings for document we want to display. Maybe anyone would know if it is even possible to display binary type files?

```
Packer.toBlob(doc).then((blob) => {
// instead of save as I want to display the file
saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
```

});